# Sync WordPress post on update: Post Title, Excerpt and Slug with Meta Title and Meta Description (SEOPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

With regular blog posts I am used to sync H1 Headline = Meta Title, Excerpt = Meta Description as follows:

1. Write meta title and description using SEOPress Pro
2. Duplicate the meta title as the post title
3. Check the slug matches the title
4. Duplicate the meta description as the post excerpt

I figured, why not add a little action, that automates this manual procedure all over the screen, on my next click on [Update]?

As of now, two actions do the job.

The first action creates a dummy post title. Just to be allowed to update the post.

The second action does the copy & paste.

Unfortunately, I have to click [Update] two or three times, in order to achieve the desired result completely.

Why is that and what can I do to reduce it to a single update click?

Thank you so much in advance!

```
add_filter('default_title', 'set_default_title');
function set_default_title() {
    global $post_type;
    if ('post' == $post_type) {
        return 'temp';
    }
}

add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'synchronize_seopress_meta', 99, 2);
function synchronize_seopress_meta($data, $postarr) {
    if ($data['post_type'] === 'post' && $data['post_status'] !== 'auto-draft') {
        $post_id = $postarr['ID'];
        $meta_title = get_post_meta($post_id, '_seopress_titles_title', true);
        $meta_description = get_post_meta($post_id, '_seopress_titles_desc', true);
        if (!empty($meta_title)) {
            $data['post_title'] = $meta_title;
            $data['post_name'] = sanitize_title( $data[$meta_title] );
        }
        if (!empty($meta_description)) {
            $data['post_excerpt'] = $meta_description;
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Meanwhile I did some further research but could not find a better solution. Aside, some minor improvements of the code above. Just to clarify the isssue: It does not matter, whether I create a new post or update an existing one. It takes 3 updates. On the first update, nothing happens at all. On the second, title and description are updated. On the third, the slug is updated, as well. If it's a new post, the update button is initially called [Publish]. Does not make any difference.